# Plotting a grouped pandas data in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
    A       B
1   USA     Y
3   USA     Y 
4   USA     N
5   India   Y
8   India   N
12  USA     N
14  USA     Y
19  USA     Y
```

I want to make a `countplot` for this dataframe. That is, the plot will have country names on `X-axis` and the counts for each category on `Y-axis`. I know I can do this in `seaborn` like this:

`sns.countplot(x='A', data=df, hue='B')`

But this will not be an interactive plot. I want to achieve the same thing in `plotly` but I am having a hard time figuring it out. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 7):

Using plotly 3 you can do something like this:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
for name, group in df.groupby('B'):
    trace = go.Histogram()
    trace.name = name
    trace.x = group['A']
    fig.add_trace(trace)
```

you can also change other properties like the colors by setting `trace.marker.color` attribute.